# how I can validate subscribers list?

Tags: email, html-email, email-validation

I have list of subscribers from my old blog. Now I want to resubscribe users to my new blog. But when I upload list to MailChimp I've been banned. From support, I know that my list isn't clean, like lots of dead mails in it. How I can improve list quality to finally start sending mailings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use email validation service, like [mailcheck](https://mailcheck.co) it's not unique service, but comparing to others they do contact enrichment. Like showing you Surname of yours prospect. It also could be helpful.

Comment: I would not upload anything to the mailcheck service given their "terms" and "about" information. https://www.mailcheck.co/terms That whole page seems to me like a phising attempt.

Comment: Hmm, looks like normal T&C, with standard phrases - like we provided services as is, with no warranties etc...

Comment: The updated terms are better, although the service still lacks a proper privacy policy stating in depth how the user’s data will be handled by the service and for how long it will be held on to. The link to the privacy policy just points back to the terms. :)